# error when running vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31.bin to install vuforia sdk

Tags: android, sdk, vuforia

i start reading Augmented reality for android application and i'm new in it. 
I need to install the vuforia SDK android-2-0-30 using Linux(ubuntu 11.10) but when i run the file vuforia-sdk-android-2-0-31.bin i get this error :
Installer User Interface Mode Not Supported

"`The installer cannot run in this UI mode. To specify the interface mode, use the -i command-line option, followed by the UI mode identifier. The valid UI modes identifiers are GUI, Console, and Silent`."

i tried to use the mode root and the other UI interfaces mentioned in the error message but always the same error
I really need help

Comment: Here's an old topic on the same/similar error; https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/i-cant-install-vuforia-ubuntu . Maybe it helped with newer Vuforia version too.